# Proper cow bones to prepare holodets

Tags: gelatin, bones

### Holodets blues

[image]

Holodets is a typical Eastern Europe recipe. It is is basically a meat aspic, the gelatin being obtained from long boiling the bones and melting the connective tissue-collagen.

I tried to do holodets using cow bones (no pig feet, that one is easier).

My problem is that I can't figure out from the recipes which bone is used. It's mentioned as "hoof", "knee", "leg bone", etc. But there is no photograph and bone names vary from place to place.

I prepared the dish but the collagen content of the bones I used was not enough, so I ended up adding agar-agar, which I know is not needed if the bones are "the correct ones".

Can anyone to help me to identify the bones? A photograph should be the optimal answer!

NB> Please feel free to correct my English

Comment: Do bone names really vary that much? The exact bone isn't so important- just that it contains enough collagen. Leg bones, hooves, and joints have a lot.

Comment: @Sobachatina I just know that my first test was a failure. I used a short bone from the leg (not sure which one) but without meat ... perhaps the tendons are important.

Comment: The tendons are not necessary. If it was a leg bone it should have had enough collagen. I would make sure that you cooked it long enough and didn't use too much water for the amount of bone.

Comment: @Sobachatina Ok, I'll try with a femur. Just answering your comment, I cooked my bones for 5 hours and used just enough water to cover them.

Comment: The Hungarian name for this is "kocsonya", and I've always despised the stuff. Give me the meat soup (húsleves) warm, please.

Comment: @Marti I plan to try that too :)

Comment: @Marti also changed "Russian-Polish-Jewish" by "Eastern Europe" ... seems that the dish geographic distribution is very broad.

Comment: @Marti- it was an acquired taste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Russian lady that taught me how to make Kholodets used a chunk of femur.

She would simmer for at least 5 hours the bone with a good bit of meat still on it. As the broth cooled she would remove the meat from the bone, chop it and put it back into the pot along with a sizeable amount of sliced garlic.

After chilling in the fridge (usually overnight) she would remove the fat that accumulated on top and serve with a very khrenoviy mustard.

I'm sure that a joint would have worked just as well- it just wouldn't have as much usable meat.

I'm sorry I don't have pictures.

Comment: Ok. "femur" is decriptive enough :) ... Did she leave the marrow in? I think the marrow will give a dark tint to the broth ...

Comment: She did leave the marrow it. Because of the length of the bone it would have been very difficult to get the marrow out.

Comment: Was the cartilage still on?

Comment: @chris yes, in fact the whole bone "cap" was on and got separated while cooking

Comment: I think the cartilage is critical to getting a good gel.  That's why they typically call for joints.

Comment: @chris, well the short bones I used had two cartilage caps each one, so the relation cartilage/bone was much better than with a femur

Comment: @Sobachatina BTW I have khren plants in my garden .... :)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about Holodet. But a good source of making gelatin from meat is the knee bone with all the cartilage in it. I use it to make foot jelly (aka gala, galarita, ptcha). This is not the same as bones with marrow. AFAIK marrow is not a big source of cartilage. You do have to simmer at low heat for a long time to get the cartilage to dissolve. Don't try a rolling boil, it wont work.

Comment: Thank you. I already tried with the knee bone (the name here is "chiquizuela") and the results were much better.

Answer (score 2):

I use, like my mother teached me, some bones named "garrón"in Argentina. She was from Polland. Are the "femur" bones.
I don't use meat, chicken or pig. Only the bones, vegetables and spices. I put the cartilages and tendons, with slice of eggs and "ajo" and over these the soup. It must be cold to be eaten.

Comment: Ajá! Y dónde lo comprás?